# How to send request to an api every day based on user schedule .Net Core MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm working on project that can send bulk comments on wordpress posts using rest api.

User can select category of wordpress posts and a group of prewritten comments and set a schedule for sending comment to wordpess, for example send comments on 5 posts every day in exact time until the posts run out.

how can I send request to wordpress rest api based on user schedule ?

Comment: search for hangfire or quartz for automatic scheduling in .NET core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to Microsoft's official documentation to learn about Background tasks.

[Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)